# Ship in game is not moving on additional key press

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating this alien invasion game from a book called Python Crash Course. The problem arising now is that the ship which I have created gets stuck once I press another key.

I have tried changing the code a bit but that doesn't work a lot, so I am providing my earlier code for someone to help me with this.

```
import sys
import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event,ship):
    """it will respond to the keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:  # detects if the key pressed is the right key
        # will move the ship to right
        ship.moving_right = True  # used for modifying the value rathr than changing the ships position we change it directlty to true
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True

    def check_keyup_events(event,ship):
        """it will respond to the key release"""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ship):

    """it will respond to keypress and mouse events."""

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:    #detects wheteher a key is pressed or not
            check_keydown_events(event,ship)

        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:      #new block to rsspond to the keyup event when the user releases the key
            check_keydown_events(event,ship)


                #it will move the ship to right

def update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship):

    """basic use was to refactor the basic developed code once again"""
    """updates images on the screen and flips to a new screen."""

    #redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    #make the most recently drawn screen visible
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Currently no error messages are coming, just the ship is not moving once I press another key.

Comment: >elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:      
        check_keydown_events(event,ship)

Should not that be check_keyup_events(event,ship)

Comment: I don't think your `def check_keyup_events` should be inside `check_keydown_events`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Fix the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) of `check_keyup_events`. The indentation should be the same as for `check_keydown_events`.
`check_keydown_events`  is called twice (in case of `pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.KEYUP`), but `check_keyup_events`is never called.

```py
def check_keydown_events(event,ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True 
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True

def check_keyup_events(event,ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ship):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            check_keydown_events(event,ship)

        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP: 
            check_keyup_events(event,ship)
```

---

The code can be simplified by using [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed):

```py
def check_events(ship):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed();
    ship.moving_right = keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]
    ship.moving_left  = keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
```

The states which are returned by `pygame.key.get_pressed()` are evaluated when the events are handled by either [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) or [`pygame.event.poll()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.poll)